# How do you parse the # hash in URL parameter using browserHistory?

Tags: reactjs, hash, react-router

This is what I currently have:

```
mysite.com/documents/{documentName}
```

{documentName} is usually alphanumeric but occassionally users title it with a # hash like this: 'quote#1930'. The URL comes out as follows...

```
mysite.com/documents/quote#1930
```

How do I deal with this? Validating document names is not an option at this point for my client. He wants the # hash tag.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash mark `#` is a special symbol in URLs, used to separate the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Basically, if you have a URL `http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar`, it will navigate to the element with ID `bar` in the document `http://www.example.org/foo.html`. I don't know of any way to include `#` in the URL without causing this behaviour.

Typically, you would URI-encode the string. The character `#` is a special character, so to represent it in a URL you would encode it as `%23`, for instance `mysite.com/documents/quote%231930`. There is a JS function `encodeURIComponent` that can perform the encoding for you.